# ¿Cómo puedo obtener un string a partir de una fecha en python?

Tags: python, date

Tengo esta fecha en UTC: Wed 26 Jun 2019 19:54:36 +0200 (este +2 es el timezone) y necesitaría pasarla a string: datetime(2019,6,26,19,54,36,0), el 0 es el día de la semana

De momento el código que tengo es este, pero no sé si es lo correcto:

```
import datetime

t = datetime.datetime(2019,6,26,19,54,36,0)
t.strftime('%d %b %Y %I:%M:%S %a')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A juzgar por tu comentario a otra respuesta, parece que lo que querías en realidad es lo contrario de lo que dice el título, es decir, lo que querías era convertir una cadena ("Sun 10 May 2015 20:54:36 +0200") en una fecha, o sea, en un objeto de tipo `datetime`.

Como ya te han respondido, eso se logra con `strptime()`. Una vez tienes el objeto `datetime` puedes usar `strftime()` en forma similar a como muestras tú mismo en la pregunta para convertirlo de nuevo en cadena, y aprovechar ese momento para especificar en qué forma quieres la cadena.

Según tu comentario quieres que sea de la forma "20150610205436", por lo que tendrás que especificar como cadena de formato "%Y%m%d%H%M%S". Es decir:

```
import datetime

fecha_str = "Sun 10 May 2015 20:54:36 +0200"
fecha = datetime.datetime.strptime(fecha_str, "%a %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z")
print(fecha.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S"))
```

**Nota**. Aprovecho para corregir un error en la pregunta, en la que dices que el valor 0 pasado como séptimo parámetro al constructor de `datetime()` es el día de la semana. Eso es incorrecto. El séptimo parámetro es la cantidad de microsegundos en la hora. El día de la semana no puedes fijarlo, ya que es automáticamente el que corresponda a esa fecha (domingo en ese ejemplo), y en todo caso el domingo sería el 6 y no el 0.

Answer (score 3):

Para convertir *cadenas de fechas* se debe utilizar la función `strptime` con la cadena de formato correspondiente. En este caso:

```
import datetime

fecha_str = "Sun 10 May 2015 20:54:36 +0200"

fecha = datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%a %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z")
```

La información sobre el formato lo tiene en : https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

Comment: Hola, gracias de antemano. He probado el código y funciona. Aparece: 2015-05-10 13:54:36+07:00. Ahora cómo puedo hacer para que me aparezca en formato 20150610135436?

Comment: Usa la función complementaria, `strftime`, con la cadena de formato adecuada, por ejemplo `"%Y%m%d%H%M%S""`.